# HTML CSS Can you ignore a div in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I made a card as part of a list of cards.  I set it up as a flexbox row and worked good.

[image]

So I wanted to make the page responsive.  Instead of the card being in a row, it seemed it was best to made a the image and a div of the text (grouped in a div as rows)  So the image and the text is one flex and the 2nd row is itself a flex in a column.  And that worked nice.

[image]

However, that extra div is breaking up my original flexbox layout.  Which I suspected might be the case.  This is the normal web browser view now.

[image]

Here's the code for the html (its a ruby ERB).

```
  <div class='search-product-card'>

    <div class='search-product-flex'>

      <%= render partial: "shared/product_image", locals: { product: results_product } %>

      <div class="search-product-mobile-flex">
        <div class="search-product-flex1">
          <%= link_to results_product.name, product_path(results_product.id) %>
        </div>
        <div class="search-product-flex2">
          <p>Imported From <%= results_product.country  %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="search-adjust-stars">
          <%= render partial: "shared/review_stars", locals: { review: results_product.average_review } %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS

```
  // Search Page
    
    
    .search-product-card {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 60%;
      height: 125px;
      border: 1px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1.5px solid #CBCBCB;
      border-top: 3px solid #419234;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      align-self: center;
    }
    

    .search-noresult-card {
      width: 60%;
      height: 40px;
      border: 1px;
      padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1.5px solid #CBCBCB;
      border-top: 3px solid #f7b8b7;
      text-align: center;
      align-self: center;
    }
    
    .search-product-flex {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    
    .search-adjust-stars {
      margin-top: 2px;
    }
    
   
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
      .search-product-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-noresult-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-review-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .search-product-flex {
        justify-content: flex-start;
      }
      .search-product-mobile-flex {
        order: 2;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
      .search-product-flex1 {
        order: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
      .search-product-flex2 {
        order: 2;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .search-adjust-stars {
        order: 3;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: -10px;
      }
    
    }
```

The new div is the "search-product-mobile-flex".  It is only used in the media query.
So I'm asking if there is way to ignore that div until it is called in the media query.

Comment: Could you provide css, please ?

Comment: Whoops, yes, added it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a media query to display your information in column just under a certain breakpoint:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;  
}

.content > div {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .content {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content > div {
    text-align: left;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"/>
  <div class="content">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set out of your media query:

```css
.search-product-mobile-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

DEMO:

```css
// Search Page
    
    
.search-product-card {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 125px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-top: 3px solid #419234;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  align-self: center;
}


.search-noresult-card {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-top: 3px solid #f7b8b7;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.search-product-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.search-adjust-stars {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.search-product-mobile-flex {
  display: flex;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  .search-product-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search-noresult-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search-review-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search-product-flex {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .search-product-mobile-flex {
    order: 2;
    /*display: flex;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .search-product-flex1 {
    order: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .search-product-flex2 {
    order: 2;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .search-adjust-stars {
    order: 3;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class='search-product-card'>

    <div class='search-product-flex'>

      <%= render partial: "shared/product_image", locals: { product: results_product } %>

      <div class="search-product-mobile-flex">
        <div class="search-product-flex1">
          <%= link_to results_product.name, product_path(results_product.id) %>
        </div>
        <div class="search-product-flex2">
          <p>Imported From <%= results_product.country  %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="search-adjust-stars">
          <%= render partial: "shared/review_stars", locals: { review: results_product.average_review } %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```